# Count all rows from a second table connected by id and add the value on the right row of the first table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, in one table i save entrys. Like for example a entry where i offer a smartphone.
 On each entry there can be more questions. Like for example a chat for customer and supplier.
This question get saved in a second table. Each question will get the "entry id".
Now i would like to get **all entrys** and count for each entry all questions as a single value.
**For example**:

```
id |title        | desc                  | questionscount
 1 |samsung s7.. | smartphone bla bla    | 11
 2 |samsung s6.. | bla bla bla           | 5
 3 |samsung s5.. | bla bla               | 0
```

I simplified my sql and i think im really close:

```
SELECT 
    e.id, e.uid, e.tmstmp, e.title, e.desc, questioncount
FROM 
    entrys e 

INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT eid, COUNT(id) as questioncount
        FROM question 
        WHERE eid = e.id
) q
```

->Unknown column 'e.id' in 'where clause'

I tried to inner join them with "on" like:

```
ON q.eid = e.id
```

but like that not all rows are selected and questioncount get the value from all question no matter if eid = e.id.

Comment: Use a subquery, or use group by with join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the count as a subquery

```
SELECT e.id, e.uid, e.tmstmp, e.title, e.desc,
(SELECT COUNT(q.id) FROM question q WHERE q.eid = e.id) AS questioncount
FROM entrys e
```

Answer (score 3):

Use left join so it will return all rows from entrys whether each entry has a question or not.

```
SELECT 
    e.id, e.uid, e.tmstmp, e.title, e.desc, COUNT(q.id) questioncount
FROM 
    entrys e 
LEFT JOIN question q on  e.id = q.eid
GROUP BY e.id
```